# Force download as ranges

Tags: php, file, range, force-download

I'm trying to force a file download, in PHP, as ranges, but the browser doesn't call the next ranges.

I surely miss something but I don't know what, any idea, please ?

My related headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.mp3"
Content-Length: 524288
Content-Range: bytes 0-524287/9289186
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: -1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

EDIT:

When I download it by curl, with a `-C -`, I got the entire file if run this many times.

```
curl [url] -o filename.mp3 -C -
```

But if I call this, I got only the first 512Ko and curl doesn't call the rest

```
curl [url] -o filename.mp3
```

Comment: If you don't know the end range `Content-Range: <unit> <range-start>-<range-end>/*`

See: [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range

Comment: @Jamie_D Thanks but I know the end range, see my ".../9289186" ;)

Comment: Self-solved, just a misunderstanding: the HTTP_RANGE is *only* sent by the browser, when a paused download is unpaused. Thx anyway, guys.